# For loop problem, after and earlier character

Tags: python, list, loops, range

So I have problem, I want the **for j loop** to start one character after the **for i loop**, but I can't use the `range()` function.

```
for i in b:
  for j in b:
    if i < j:
      print(i * 2)
      print(j * 2)
      break
```

Comment: Is the variable b a list?

Comment: Hi, is there something special about `b`? Why can range not be used?

Comment: can you use `enumerate`?

Comment: Hi, could you give a bit context of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Can you clarify the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If range isn't allowed at all, then here's a version with enumerate.

```
for index, i in enumerate(b):
    for j in b[index:]:
        if i < j:
          print(i * 2)
          print(j * 2)
          break
```

<s>Use the length of the list as the end of the range, and the index `i` as the start of the range for the second loop.</s>

```
for i in range(len(b)):
  for j in range(i, len(b)):
    if b[i] < b[j]:
      print(b[i] * 2)
      print(b[j] * 2)
      break
```

Comment: I believe the question says he can't use range()?

Comment: That's definitely my bad. I saw that he was new to python so I made some assumptions that I shouldn't have.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `range` and a for-loop, you can use a while-loop that tests if a counter is less than the size of your iterable object `b`.

```py
size_of_b = len(b)

i = 0
while i < size_of_b:
    # Set j to one more than i
    j = i + 1
    while j < size_of_b:
        if b[i] < b[j]:
            print(b[i] * 2)
            print(b[j] * 2)
            # Break out of the inner "while j" loop
            break

        # Increment "j" for the inner "while j" loop
        j += 1

    # Increment "i" for the outer "while i" loop
    i += 1
```

For a more advanced pythonic way of doing it, you could use [the `enumerate` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). It returns the index and the value for each step of the iterable:

```py
# Here I'm using more descriptive variable names so it's easier to follow.
for outer_index, outer_value in enumerate(items):
    # For the inner loop, we can slice the list so it starts on 1 + the outer_index
    inner_index = outer_index + 1
    for inner_value in items[inner_index:]:
        if outer_value < inner_value:
            print(outer_value * 2, inner_value * 2, sep="\n")
            break
```